# Laravel, All on click events on my website have stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I have a very strange error on my application, where almost all of my onclick events have stopped working, routing to another page or calling a function. Some of them when I right click I can open in another tab.
Few things I like to mention.

1. I don't get any error regarding in my console.
2. I am using Laravel 5.7.
3. Using Bootstrap 4.
4. Doesn't work on localhost as well as server.

Please help me where am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

There's a lot of code and I don't know what to share to specify the problem.

Comment: Are you newly added any `jQuery / JS` code ? I think may `JS` have prevent click events...

Comment: Put your view code here.

Comment: I have found that cloudflare rocketloader has broken onclicks before in my code.

Comment: @kobe so how did you solve it then?

Comment: @TaimoorBadar By not using it :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) bookmarklet to check all your events attached to your DOM elements and see if there was attached some events that prevent the other.

Comment: I have installed the Visual Event and it gives me the detail of events but still can't understand that which event is blocking which. Can you explain please how can I do  that.